# Does try() suffer performance difference between Rails 3.0.x and Rails 3.2.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, performance, exception

Many people use try to handle uncertain chaining.  Let's leave aside whether or not such chaining is a good practice.

- [Rails 3.0.x](http://ruby-docs.com/docs/ruby_1.9.3-rails_3.0.12/Rails%203.0.12/classes/Object.html#method-i-try) seems to have no separate handling of the `try` for the `NilClass`
- Rails 3.2.x handle [`nil.try`](http://ruby-docs.com/docs/ruby_1.9.3-rails_3.1.4/Rails%203.1.4/classes/NilClass.html#method-i-try) differently than [`object.try`](http://ruby-docs.com/docs/ruby_1.9.3-rails_3.1.4/Rails%203.1.4/classes/Object.html#method-i-try)

Does this difference lead to the `nil.try` case being faster on Rails > 3.0.x ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`try` [does exist](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6ef9fda1a39f45e2d18aba4881f60a19589a2c77/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/try.rb#L54) on NilClass, but in ActiveSupport 3.0.4 was not located in a way that is as transparent as 3.1.x